# Facebook SDK 5 php: "Graph returned an error: Unsupported post request."

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook post to page, SDK 5 php.

Like the titel says, "`Graph returned an error: Unsupported post request.`" I can't figure out why I'm getting it, tried every tip I've found both here on Stackoverflow and other websites.

I've tried to change settings in the app and page, tried small changes in the code, diffrent tokens and so on. Any tips on how I should proceed?

```
session_start();
include ('../assets/db_conn.php');

require_once __DIR__ . '/FacebookSDK/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

include('fbData.php');

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook($fbData);

    $access_token = '**';

   //////////*DB CONNECTIONS HERE*////////Took it away to make the code cleaner
    $pages = $getFbPages->fetchAll();

    $params = array();
$params["message"] = 'test1';
$params["link"] = 'http://***.se';
$params["picture"] = 'https://www.****.com/WNI01_14-Logo-275x63.png';
$params["description"] = 'testar en beskrivning';

    foreach ($pages as $page) {

        $pageID    = $page['pageId'];

        // post to Facebook
        try {
          // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
          $response = $fb->post('/'.$pageID.'/feed', $params, $access_token);
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
          echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
          echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        }

        $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

    }
```

Comment: "Unsupported get request" is returned whenever you can't access something (your URL is wrong, the post has been deleted, you don't have access to the post, etc). Try your request in the Graph API Explorer to make sure you have the necessary permissions to make the request you're making with the SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Answer (score 0):

error is due to your domain name or call back URL that you provided in App creation but may be you are testing on any other URL. Your testing URl must be sub domain or any other related to your domain